# How to get document ids of a firestore collection

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my firestore strcuture. i want to get 'RecodeBook' collections's document id's to a List in dart.

i looked everywhere for a solution here. but i could not find.

[here is the image link of firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUDNp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use getDocuments() method, you'll end up with querysnapshot. Get DocumentSnapshot with .documents. Print their documentId in a loop.

```
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection("RecodeBook").getDocuments();
var list = querySnapshot.documents;
list.forEach((f) {
  print(f.documentID);
});
```